# Minimization is equal to minimization over intervals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given a function class $\mathcal{F}$ of square integrable functions and a function $g$, let

$$ f^* := \underset{f \in \mathcal{F}}{\operatorname{argmin}} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) (f(x) - g(x))  {\rm d} x $$

Is it possible to split the minimization problem as follows?

$$ \underset{f \in \mathcal{F}}{\operatorname{argmin}} \int_{0}^{a}  f(x) (f(x) - g(x))  {\rm d} x + \underset{f \in \mathcal{F}}{\operatorname{argmin}} \int_{a}^{\infty}  f(x) (f(x) - g(x))  {\rm d} x $$

The idea is that the two argmin should optimize on separate intervals so it should still give $f^*$, but I couldn't formalize it.

E.g., the class $\mathcal{F}$ is the class of all decreasing square integrable bounded and right continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: This depends a lot on the class of functions $\mathcal{F}$, so you should specify this class. In particular, why do you even know the minimizer exists over $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: @Jeff That class in my case would be the class of all decreasing square integrable bounded and right continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ which vanish at infinity. Aren't there general rules to split such minimization problems? Even just a reference would be very helpful.

Comment: Also, it has been proved that the minimizer exists.

Comment: No, you can’t split it due to the decreasing constraint. You need the $f(a)$ in the first part to be at least as much as the $f(a)$ in the second part. If you find optimal functions for both parts and this happens to be true, then you more good to go, but otherwise combing the two function pieces wouldn’t give you an allowed function in the space. It does give you an inequality however.

Comment: @Eric You are right. I agree, thank you! By any chance, do you know any reference where I can study more in-depth these techniques about optimization?